# How do I filter a table by year and have just rows of day & month?

Tags: sql

So I have a table such as:

```
-------------------------------------
date           |    # of customers
-------------------------------------
2008-06-02     |      100
2009-06-03     |      200
-------------------------------------
```

I want to create a table where I can compare the number of customers by year for specific times of the year.  So here's what I want to create:

```
------------------------------------------------------
date           |   2008 customers   |  2009 customers
------------------------------------------------------
06-02          |     100            |   0
06-03          |     0              |   200
```

Anyone know how to create such a table?

Comment: Search for `Pivot table`, there are plenty of examples.

Comment: @Kaf: Pivot will be needed but that's not the only issue. Grouping by dates regardless of the year also needs some thinking.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT create a table for this - at the very least, create a view - but don't store data like this. Please say what your database system is - there is a known query for this, but it varies quite a bit from one system to another.

```
select datepart(month, my_date), datepart(day, my_date), count(1)
from my_table
group by datepart(month, my_date), datepart(day, my_date)
```

In SQL Server, that will give you the count of records for each month/day combination regardless of year.